# Android - Best Way to be listen to the Server Frequently for New Messages and Status

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, handler, runnable

I have been trying to develop an android app like whatsapp, hike, etc....
I'm using **SQLITE DATABASE** to store messages local including images byte-codes.

I'm using the **Runnable Handler** with **postDelayed()** method of 3 seconds, which means every 3 seconds, the application connects with server for new messages and status be drawn, updated in listView and saved in sqllite database.

Now I'm facing trouble if the number of incoming messages are more say 150-200 messages.... the handler re-launch the code before the previous all 150 messages stored in database.

```
handler = new Handler();
     handler.post(runnableCode);

Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            if (check.check(1)) { //Check for Network Connection
                asyncExecute = false;
                getNewMessages(); //Calling method of asynctask for New Messages
            }
             handler.postDelayed(this, 3000); //Run this every 3 seconds
    }
};
```

So, what I want is, till all my messages get saved in database and images downloaded completed, the handler should not be called. After saved and downloaded fully, the next handler should be called.

Tell me the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Use a Service for long running background operations and 3 seconds is to much make it 30 seconds.

Comment: Yeah,I'm using background task.But making it 30 seconds is much longer time.You just imagine when you chat with your friend,the messages updated only once in 30 seconds makes the chatting application bored and tired

Answer (score 3):

The way you did it may work but it's not a good way of doing it.
The way you got your solution together have a huge performance problem of consuming a lot of battery from the celular radio by keeping keeping it awake everytime even when the server doesn't have anything new.
If you want a more detailed explanation about this you can check it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html).

To solve this problem you can do it in two ways:
1- Implement Google Cloud Messaging(GCM) on your app and server. When the user first opens the app you register the device to GCM, get key generated for you representing your device and send it to your server so that you can save it along side the user information.

Whenever a message comes for this user, all you need to do on your server is to look for the user devices IDs(multiple if you let him sign in on different phones at same time or single) and send a message to GCM passing the device id and the payload.

On your app side you can implement a broadcast receiver that waits for incoming GCM messages and you process them as you like.

2- The second way, that I think it is simpler is to user the new [GCMNetworkManager](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html) to help you with this and also some more features as scheduling tasks etc.

Comment: Create your own GCM? you can create something like but if time is not by your side it can be a long process and you might run into some issues while developing that of course have been already solved on the GCM

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought on a bidirectional connection with the server? If you make one for example, with WebSockets the client could just need to wait for new updates coming from the server in real time.

Here you have an example of socket.io (a WebSockets library) working on android:

> [Native socket.io and android](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/)

Another library including support for HTTP, Websocket, raw sockets and socket.io

> [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)

Comment: You mean,they actually wait and get messages from server...If so,Is there any duration should be given or not...

Comment: @HarishKumar nope, you don't need to specify any duration, or something like that. You don't need to ask the server for new messages with WebSockets because you'll be in a bidirectional connection with it and it will be able to send messages to you as soon as they are handled.

Comment: I want to know is there any If-clause condition to wait for my messages and images to be download and saved in sqlite database,till the next connection for new message to be started